# Powershell function scope for opening new terminal window

Tags: powershell

I'm using a powershell function to open a new terminal window. I'd like to be able to, run a script in this window that has access to the function's parameters. But inside the `start powershell` block, the function's parameters are unavailable:

```
function startChalk([string] $thing) {
  echo "thing is $thing"  # this works - here we have access to $thing
  start powershell {
    echo "now it's $thing" # this fails - here we have no access to $thing
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make these parameters available?

Comment: What's the purpose of starting a new instance of PS?

Comment: In this case I have three projects with some overlapping code, and each window shows the (automatic) compilation of a particular project. As the source is changed I can easily see whether it's broken any project. I think there'd be lots of uses though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a (properly escaped) expandable string (`"like $this"`) for the argument instead of a scriptblock literal:

```
function startChalk([string] $thing) {
  echo "thing is $thing"  # this works - here we have access to $thing
  powershell -Command "echo 'now it''s $thing'" # this fails - here we have no access to $thing
}
```

Comment: In this toy case, the command string you suggest isn't too long so it looks ok. But if there were, say, 6 commands to run within the powershell window it would look pretty ugly to have to build an escaped string for it. I'd much rather just have a nice readable code block, so I was hoping that was possible. Is it a compiler bug that makes the behavior different for a string vs scriptblock?